# node-red - httpNodeAuth setting appears to be ignored

Tags: node-red

I have node-red setup as an Azure Web App (via https://github.com/jmservera/node-red-azure-webapp).

The editor is secured using the adminAuth setting in settings.js which works fine.

I have a simple flow with http-in and http-response nodes and a database lookup in the middle.   To secure use of the flow I have set the httpNodeAuth setting as follows (actual username and hash changed of course):

```
httpNodeAuth: {user:"myuser",pass:"passwordhashedasperauthadminmethod"},
```

However this setting appears to be completely ignored.  Running this flow from a fresh browser does not result in any authentication popup and the result of the database query is returned.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You have restarted node-red after making the change?

Comment: Yep, several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Azure Web App implementation runs in Embedded Mode and according to the node-red doco, httpAdminAuth is a Standalone Only option.   I assume, by extension, that this is true for httpNodeAuth also hence the described behaviour.